# sql data change

Tags: unpivot

Currently my data looks like this:

```
A          15902   8.11        9.20        7           8           5        6
```

A          15902    2021    8.11     7        5
A          15902    2022    9.20     8        6

```
I'm quite unsure how to do this. 

Any help is greatly appreciated!
```

Comment: Have you already tried any query?

Comment: What's your actual input? I take it it's not a table, since few database systems allow duplicate column names. Speaking of which, what database system are you using? Add a tag for it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, sorry I changed it up a bit to match more closely with what I'm using.

Comment: @lemon I tried to use CROSS APPLY but wasn't successful in using it

Comment: Check Joel's query in the answers section.

Comment: You've made the question empirically worse with those edits, and I see no reason why the tags should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot this using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  t.Hospital,
  t.Zip,
  v.Year,
  v.Paid$,
  v.Visits,
  v.LOS
FROM [MyTable] T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (2021, Paid$_21, Visits21, LOS21),
    (2022, Paid$_22, Visits22, LOS22)
) v(Year, Paid$, Visits, LOS)
```

Note that this only queries the base table once.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e87ba6ff4b435b4d3e895ae97f64ece2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Hospital, Zip, '2021' As Year, 
    Paid$_21 As Paid$, Visits21 as Visits, LOS21 as LOS
FROM [MyTable] 

UNION

SELECT Hospital, Zip, '2022' As Year, 
    Paid$_22 As Paid$, Visits22 as Visits, LOS22 as LOS
FROM [MyTable]
```

You can also try [`UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16#unpivot-example)

Comment: Not sure why you need to query the table twice, nor why it needs `UNION` as opposed to `UNION ALL`